# ProcessBuilder Throwing IO Exception when executing a batch file more than once

Tags: java, batch-file, process, processbuilder

I am trying to run a batch file from my java application using Processbuilder and using an api to call this Processbuilder. When I run the api for the first time the Processbuilder is able to locate the batch file and then it is doing the intended actions. But when I run the api for the second time without bouncing the application, I am getting an IO Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "I:/test/test.bat": The system cannot find the path specified
```

This is how my code looks
Service layer:

```
@Override
public String submitRequest() {
    List<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
    String scriptPath = "I:\\test\\test.bat";
    command.add(scriptPath);
    int exitCode= runCommandWithLog(logFilePath,command);
}

 public int runCommandWithLog(String logFile, List<String> command)  {
    int exitCode = -1;
    try{
         logger.info("Running the batch file located at {}", command.get(0));
        logger.info(String.valueOf(Files.exists(Path.of(scriptPath))));
        ProcessBuilder pb =  new ProcessBuilder(command)
                .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo(new File(logFile + ".log")))
                .redirectError( ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo(new File(logFile + ".err")));

        Process p = pb.start();
        logger.info("Starting the batch file with the logger function");
        p.waitFor(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        exitCode = p.exitValue();
        logger.info("Process has been destroyed");
        logger.info("Exit Code for the Execution {}" ,exitCode);        }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return exitCode;
}
```

PS stack Trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "I:/test/test.bat": The system cannot find the path specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at com.jpmc.ct.tcio.securities.service.impl.ShellSeriveImpl.runCommandWithLog(ShellSeriveImpl.java:90)
    at com.jpmc.ct.tcio.securities.service.impl.ShellSeriveImpl$ConsumerWorkerThread.run(ShellSeriveImpl.java:141)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.openForAtomicAppend(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.newFileOutputStream(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:135)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Might be an idea to post the *full* stack trace in the question (formatted as code). Is there anything in that error log? Why are you closing the process streams? You shouldn't be doing. Those streams are taken care of by the redirects

Comment: I have added the stak trace @g00se

Comment: `System.out.println(Files.exists(Path.of(scriptPath)));` tells you what?

Comment: true on both instances

Comment: Are there any paths *inside* that batch file? Also, try `command = List.of("cmd.exe", "/c", scriptPath);`

Comment: I don't think you can run a batch file directly, instead, you need to run it via a `cmd` context

Comment: I tried including the List.of("cmd.exe", "/c", scriptPath); still the same issue.
@MadProgrammer I am able to run the first time, the issue comes when I execute it a second time or n number of times after the first time

Comment: @g00se no there are no paths inside the batch file

Comment: I wouldn't be doing `p.getInputStream().close(); p.getOutputStream().close(); p.getErrorStream().close();` - you shouldn't be ignoring the streams as some processes will stop running if the streams are filled. I'm not sure you need `p.destory()` after the process has exited - you might only need it if `waitFor` returns before the process exits, so you should be checking it's state first

Comment: Well, I already mentioned about the closing of the streams. I hope that's been acted upon ;)

Comment: I actually added them to see if that was causing the error, meaning if the unclosed streams were causing this issue, but even when I removed it, it is still same case

Comment: *But when I run the api for the second time without bouncing the application* What do those last three words mean?

Comment: Modified the question with the changes you mentioned

Comment: Bouncing the application - restarting the application, stop and start the entire jar or java applicaiton, if you may

Comment: You will probably *need* to stop the app each time fully before each run - Java has a habit of locking files

Comment: thats strange, is there a way to release the lock without stopping the application?

Comment: That stack trace seems to point to the standard output as the problem, not the batch file, no?

Comment: *thats strange, is there a way to release the lock without stopping the application?* Not saying that's definitely the case, but I definitely would terminate each time. There's also locking of redirect files to consider. Does it work then if you do? *That stack trace seems to point to the standard output as the problem, not the batch file, no?* Possibly. Check those log file (redirect) paths are OK

Comment: [I know no java] Does anything actually *terminate* the batch?

Comment: The redirect paths are fine too @g00se

Comment: OK that's good, but those files might be locked, making it impossible to write to them from another process at the same time. You can test that hypothesis by generating unique redirect file names. If it then works as expected, then the stderr and/or the stdout files were the only ones locked (i.e. not the batch file)